# Opposite of __ALL__ in python (for excluding functions)

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm quite sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find an answer (I must be searching the wrong terms).

The `__all__` variable in python allows you to explicitly note the functions you want included on a global import. I wondered: is there a similar variable (something like `__exclude__`) that includes `__all__` in a global import with the exception of those functions placed in `__exclude__`?

There are some functions I'd like sphinx to ignore for documentation, and sphinx seems to rely on `__all__`. But, when I implement new functionality, I'll occasionally forget to add it to `__all__` which can be frustrating. It would be much easier to *assume* everything is to be used with the exception of a few named functions in a variable. Is this possible?

Again, sorry if this is a repeat.

Comment: The premise of the question seems to be that you can remedy "I'll occasionally forget to add it to `__all__`" by having another list that you're equally likely to forget to add things to?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. It's extremely rare (at least for my project) to write something that I really want excluded (only 2 out of ~20 functions so far). But I'm adding features all the time!

Comment: if you do not want them to be documented, why not just prefix them with `_` (`_internal_function`) ?

Comment: @python_user Sphinx autodoc relies on `__all__`. I think, if there is a solution to the question above, it would be more elegant, but otherwise it might be better to remove `__all__` and use `exclude-members`.

Comment: @LukePoeppel ok I understand, as the default behavior of `__all__` is to not inculde `_underscore_names` this avoids you having to manually maintain it correct? the default `__all__` will not include your "internal methods" and hence will not be documented, if you don't want something documented, then chances are it is not meant to be used by others outside the library, so it is ok to have it prefixed with an underscore